# How to cache and reuse binary files, downloaded during build script?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, caching, docker-compose, binary

I am struggling to find a way to cache all dependencies and binary files, downloaded during the build script (including building DB content).

What I am aiming at -> docker-compose file with two images - one that has to be built and another image (currently nginx) which to catch all the traffic from the first image's terminal (build time) and cache all downloaded binaries in a volume folder, so the next build could use them, instead of downloading again.
I am passing env. variable so the terminal http and https traffic to go through the proxy server, but it doesn't seem to work. (http_proxy: 0.0.0.0:8080
https_proxy: 0.0.0.0:8080) ->
When the nginx container is up, executing the command in another cmd window

```
curl http://google.com --proxy http://localhost:8080
```

is returing **"301 Moved"**, which is fine -> so I guess the http proxy is somehow working, but not the way I need it.

Could you please give me some directions on how to proceed (nginx is not a must if you have a better alternative, which can cache and store binary files for later use)? 
Thank you in advance!